# Posting File and JSON data in apache CXF

Tags: apache, jax-rs, cxf

i am using Apache CXF RESTful webservice to upload a file at the same time sending JSON data to as shown:

```
@POST
    @Path( "/upload/doc" )
    @Consumes( { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
    public Response uploadRateSheet( @Multipart( value = "file" ) Attachment attachment, DocumentApiModel doc)
    {
        ...

}
```

i am using REST client to send JSON data and file.
when i send the request, i am getting foll error:

```
No message body reader has been found for class DocumentApiModel
```

please help...

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

1. As I believe you cannot send an attachment and body together(Verified in CXF webclient, chrome postman and restclient), Either you can send attachment or body separately.

   Hence updated rest defination with multiple parts.
2. Next CXF to apply provider it has to know what is the content-type for each part,

   Hence set the content-type.

With Above two changes your REST method declaration would look like shown below.

```
@POST
@Path( "/upload/doc" )
@Consumes( { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public Response uploadRateSheet( 
      @Multipart( value = "file",type="application/octet-stream") Attachment attachment, //Note set content type accordinly such that if any available providers for that content type is present it can resolve your attachment implicitly to avoid writing custom code.
      @Multipart( value = "docModel",type="application/json") DocumentApiModel doc);
```

1. Next make sure you have enabled JSON providers such as Jettission or Jackson

   For Example Jackson Json provider

   ```
   <jaxrs:providers>
      <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider"/>
   </jaxrs:providers>
   ```
2. Finally testing, note you have to set both parts using file, it seems rest client does not set content type in Content-Disposition when you choose String.

[image]

3. Alternatively you can test using CXF Webclient.

   ```
   @Test
   public void testMultipart() throws FileNotFoundException{

       WebClient client = WebClient.create("<your service url>", Arrays.asList(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider()));
       client.type("multipart/form-data");
       final Attachment attachment = new Attachment("file", new FileInputStream("<your file>"), new ContentDisposition(("attachment;filename=filename")));
       final Attachment attachment1 = new Attachment("docModel","application/json",new DocumentApiModel());
       client.post(new MultipartBody(Arrays.asList(attachment, attachment1)));

   }
   ```